# Username, ID, Password, can't identify what's wrong

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I wanted to make a "log-in" system, so you make a username, through `Input` then give the username an ID (between 1 and x). The username and ID will be stored in document: "tomtdokument.txt" (it's norwegian)

My idea forward would be to then maybe put the ID into another document with a password, which will also be chosen by `Input`. However, haven't gotten close to that step yet. That´s my general idea, but I'm having a hard time adding the username to the ID.

I'm not sure what do to, because I'm not sure what the problem is, there's no Error code. So there's no problem with the code, but it won't do its purpose, and it won't write the username in the file.

Anyway, my code is below, and the problem I would assume is in the while-loop, probably in the if-statement:

```
import random

username = str(input("Username please: "))
ran = random.randint(1, 10)
ran = str(ran)
print(ran)

f = open("tomtdokument.txt", "w")

start_number = 1
amount_lines = 10

while amount_lines >= start_number:
    z = str(start_number) + "\n"
    f.write(z)
    if start_number == ran:
        f.write(ran + username)
    start_number += 1

f.close()
```

Comment: So, not sure if I clarified the question enought, but the only thing that gets added to the file "tomtdokument.txt" is the number, so in line 1, it says 1, line 2, 2, and so on, and with the if-statement I want it to add the username behind the ID, but it don´t so, not sure what to do.

Comment: You are comparing strings with numbers, so that wont work. Try: `if str(start_number) == ran:`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but im not sure why I cant mark your your question as the answer, theres no check mark, nor a way to mark my question as solved, how?

Comment: Someone (or you if you want) has to post it as an actual answer (not a comment) for you to be able to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:
`z = str(start_number) + "\n"`
you don't add the username anywhere. and i think that's what you want
you must concatenate the user and the id and then write them over a file

**I have 2 suggestions for you.**

**First**
i didn't understand very well what do u want do, but i just changed this from your code:
**This is more pythonic**

```
z = f'{str(start_number)}{username}\n' # u can change order if you want, put username firts, whatever.
```

**Second**
wrote a code that I think fits what you want to do.
test it

```
import sys
import random

def save_user(username):
   file = open('tomtdokument.txt', 'a')
   file.write(username)
   file.close()

def main():
   username_in = str(input('Please, type your username or 0 for exit: '))
   if username_in == '0': sys.exit() # this line is to end the execution of the program
   random_id = random.randrange(1,10)
   username = "{}{}\n".format(username_in, str(random_id))
   save_user(username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   while True:
      main()
```

**if you have more questions you can ask them**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare `start_number` which is an integer and `ran` is string:

```
if start_number == ran:
```

Try doing something like this:

```
while amount_lines >= start_number:
    z = str(start_number) + "\n"
    if str(start_number) == ran:
        f.write(ran + " " + username + "\n")
    else:
        f.write(z)
    start_number += 1
```